# How to represent a 3D terrain with a x, y, z coordinate system?

Tags: 3d

I would like to program a three dimensional grid (or terrain), but I am having trouble creating the "grid". The grid will be represented with lines at each interval, and connect to the adjacent point. I think I bit off more than I can chew when I realized I couldn't even draw (render) a 2D grid. Putting this aside, how would I go about making a grid, that looks like a net because of the lines, and have the ability to manipulate each individual point to create a "terrain"?

Comment: Can you tell us about what technology you are using for this project? Programming language? Framework? Libraries? Anything?

Comment: I am using Java in Eclipse IDE. I am not sure what "Framework" is, but

Comment: I am using JRE and JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a terrain in a similar way you create any 3d mesh, so you'll probably need an index buffer and a vertex buffer. A simple grid can be drawn with lines, where you'll need two points per line, but a more advanced one will generally use triangles or quads.

You can create your terrain programmatically, i.e. just use a loop to populate index array and vertex array with numbers that form a grid or you can use something like depth maps, i.e. pictures with color representing height of your terrain.

For more advanced terrain you'll probably want to have a look at quadtree data structure which will allow you to efficiently render and manipulate your terrain, quickly calculate height and any given point, implement level of detail etc.

Comment: Could you explain how the index and vertex buffer would work? With nodes? Also, I would prefer it to be generated with triangles as to where the vertices could be easily manipulated.

Comment: They are just arrays. The exact format will depend on the graphics API you're using. Generally you'll store all points of the terrain (vertices) in a vertex array and use index array to point which vertices form triangles. You'll then pass this data to rendering pipeline for drawing.